# Compare a string to an integer

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I'm just learning how to use python and lists.  I have a sample list like the one below.

```
list = [['Ferrari','200,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','230,000','10,000km'],['Ferrari','150,000','10,000km'],['Ferrari','200,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','230,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','200,210','10,000km'],['Ferrari','110,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','400,000','10,000km'],
```

I'm trying to run a loop that checks if the 2nd element in each nested list is greater than 350,000, then prints the car, price, and mileage if it is.

I've used different `for` loops with an `if` statement inside of it, but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly do not name your variable `list` as it shadows the builtin.

This is a very simple approach of solving your problem

```
>>> l = [['Ferrari','200,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','230,000','10,000km'],['Ferrari','150,000','10,000km'],['Ferrari','200,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','230,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','200,210','10,000km'],['Ferrari','110,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','400,000','10,000km']]
>>> for i in l:
...     if (int(i[1].replace(',','')) > 350000):      # Remove all the , in your string and type cast it to an integer
...          print i
... 
['Porsche', '400,000', '10,000km']
```

You can do it in a list comprehension as in `[i for i in l if int(i[1].replace(',','')) > 350000 ]` which will do everything for you in a single line

Comment: Thank you.  My issue was actually that the 2nd element was a string and  not an integer.

Answer (score 4):

The answer above is excellent, though for anyone just starting out with programming in general you may be confused with the following:

```
int(`i[1]`.replace(',',''))
```

What that is doing is taking your item in the list, for example `['Porsche', '400,000', '10,000km']`, and next if finds the second element in that list which in this case is `'400,000'`. It does this with `i[1]`.

You now have found the element you want to check if its larger than 350,000. However, the element you have is a string, not a number. You must convert this string to a integer.

The first step in doing this is to remove the special characters (the commas). The function `.replace(',','')` does this by looking for ',' and replacing with nothing (effectively removing anything with a ',').

At this point you have a string without any special characters in it, you have taken '400,000' and turned it into '400000'. You now have to turn it into a integer for python to understand whether or not its smaller or larger than 350000. Thankfully, python makes this very easy. The function `int()` does all the work. Specifically, `int('400000')` turns '400000' into 40000.

You may now compare 400000 to 350000 and move along with your day.

Comment: FWIW, this is why we need you to include what you did with your code, even (especially!) when it doesn't work.  Kudos to Justin for figuring it out, but you gave us nothing to go on.

Comment: Yep, Justin, it was a really good answer but you must have added the code! You get a +1 from me!

Answer (score 3):

One nice thing about Python is that it's possible to write very readable code:

```
cars = [['Ferrari','200,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','230,000','10,000km'],
        ['Ferrari','150,000','10,000km'],['Ferrari','200,000','10,000km'],
        ['Porsche','230,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','200,210','10,000km'],
        ['Ferrari','110,000','10,000km'],['Porsche','400,000','10,000km']]

for car, price, mileage in cars:
    if (int(price.replace(',', '')) > 350000):  # convert to int and compare
         print car, price, mileage
```

It can also make it easy to handle converting strings to numeric values whose formatting might vary depending on the country (such as what character is used as the thousands separator).

This means you could also have done this which would work in other countries (assuming the numbers in the list were formatted according the its conventions):

```
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')  # set locale to platform default

for car, price, mileage in cars:
    if (locale.atoi(price) > 350000):  # convert to int and compare
         print car, price, mileage
```